# idiomatic go way for populate items using database/sql raw queries and go channels

Tags: database, postgresql, go, goroutine, idioms

I need to populate slice of aggregated items for each record from PostgreSQL database using "database/sql" package and "pq" driver, how we should do it in Go in an idiomatic way?

For my query, I need to get the user list first, then I need to populate aggregated reactions for each user, so I think I need to use goroutine and channels for the second part.

For efficiency probably we should populate items with an approach that has minimum DB.Query() open and close operations. Because each open connection has a huge impact on latency. These are my models

```golang
type User struct {
  UserId uint
  Username string
}

type Reactions struct {
  Id uint
  Emoji string
  UserId unit
  ReactedBy uint
}
```

in reactions schema the <reacted_by,user_id,emoji> triple is unique.

I need aggregated reactions grouped by emoji for each user in the user list, this is my aggregated query that should be calculated for each user in the list

```sql
select count(reactions.id) from reactions group by reactions.emoji where user_id = ?
```

the result response is something like this:

```
{
  "Users": [
    {
      "User": {
        "UserId": 1,
        "Username": "lm0nd"
      },
      "Reactions": {
        "like": 4,
        "smile": 8,
        "angry": 12
       }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: This statement is wrong: "For efficiency probably I need to use goroutine and channels". For clarity and efficiency, retrieve your results in a single goroutine unless you have additional processing that needs to be done for each row that warrants its own goroutine.

Comment: @BurakSerdar, so for my query, I need to get the user list first, then I need to populate aggregated reactions for each user, so I think I need to use goroutine and channels for the second part.

Comment: Why?  From your description, it sounds like it is a sequential process. Sharing the same db connection from multiple goroutines can be problematic, depending on the underlying driver

Comment: Also don't do a query for each user. Get data for all users with one query. Something along the lines of `select user_id, count(reactions.id) from reactions group by user_id, reactions.emoji [where user_id in (...)]`

Comment: @BurakSerdar yeah its sequential, but I didn't want to share db connection, for the second part I have two option, One is that run single reaction query with `in(userId list)` condition, and then bind each user record to the first result or get each reaction record in single query for each user, I wonder if there is any better soloution

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, for each user I need list of reactions grouped by emoji, this isn't a single row for each user

Comment: @HosseinNazari: yeah, so? Fill the user structs gradually, as you go through that resultset.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you mean that I get multiple records for each <user,reaction> pair in a single query, and bind all of them to user result item?

Comment: @HosseinNazari: not sure what you mean by "bind" exactly, but yes, it should be possible to update an existing user result object when you see another reaction row for it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I mean "fill" :), sorry, ok, it's another option, thanks

Comment: @HosseinNazari it sounds like you are trying to manually join two result sets. Run one query with the join, and process the results.